# Is it true that at Tarapith, bhoga is first offered to Bamakhepa and then to Tara Maa?

Tags: tara, bamakhepa

I had heard that at the Tarapith temple (Birbhum, West Bengal), food offerings (bhoga nivedana) is done first to Sri Sri Bamakhepa and after that to Maa Tara, the reason being that no mother can eat before her child eats.

Is it true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I have heard the same. It's true. There's an incident behind it. It's  perhaps without any written record to corroborate the same. But the ritual followed in the Tarapith temple is enough proof of this incident to be reliable.

The legend has it that once Bamakhepa was caught red-handed having the bhog meant for the Goddess. As a punishent he was banished from the temple services and perhaps was thrown out of the temple complex. Few days later Rani Bhavani (whose family had built the temple) had a dream that Ma Tara is unfed and extremely upset. The Goddess complained that she has not taken any bhog since her child Bamakhepa had been banished from the temple. Post that Bamakhepa's services was restored respectfully. And since then the practise of offering bhog to Bamakhepa became a tradition following the advise of the Goddess.